# Combining dichotomous and continuous outcomes in a meta analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, standardization, odds-ratio

I have data on weight gain from a set of studies that is both continuous and binomial. The continuous data is the mean weight at the end of the trial of the two trial arms and the binomial data is the number of events (weight gain greater than  a % of body weight or weight gain greater than a certain weight i.e. 200 lbs) and number of patients randomised by trial.

I found on the Cochrane website that I can pool these results by taking the log odds of the binomial data and multiplying by $\sqrt3/\pi$, I have three questions regarding this method. Note, I have read Chinn 2000 but I don't think it really answered my following question.

1. The variance of a logistic distribution is $(s^2\pi^2)/3$, given $s^2$ is not in this formula are we assuming variance is equal to 1, and is this a strong assumption?
2. This formula standardises the difference of the log odds of the two arms, is pooling results of SMD and the standardised difference of log odds meaningful? Intuitively it feels like this shouldn't be done?
3. Would this method still be valid if the continuous outcome was change from baseline rather than weight at the end?

Comment: What kind of events does the binomial data represent?

Comment: Ah sorry, I should've clarified, the events are weight gain above a threshold, it could be a change greater than a % of body weight or greater than a certain weight i.e. 200 lbs.